# Glowing effect with ImageMagick 7

Tags: imagemagick

i'm trying to fix my "add a glowing effect to my pngs" script. It was working in IM6 but not in IM7.

The command in IM6 was the following :
convert my_file.png ( +clone -channel A -blur 0x2.5 -level 0,80% +channel +level-colors white ) -compose DstOver -composite png32:my_new_file.png 
This would transform this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLqgI.png) to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZkjF.png)

But with IM7, the command is the same except i replaced convert with magick because Windows would complain
and the command transforms this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcIi0.png) to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XovIp.png). There's now a white background instead of the glowing effect.

The guy who wrote the script originally isn't me so i'm a bit lost with IM commands

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in Imagemagick 7 from Imagemagick 6.  In Imagemagick 7, you need to enable transparency for all channels.

So add -alpha on -channel rgba to the command after reading the input.

Unix Syntax:

```
magick my_file.png -alpha on -channel rgba \( +clone -channel A -blur 0x2.5 -level 0,80% +channel +level-colors white \) -compose DstOver -composite png32:my_new_file2.png
```

Windows Syntax:

```
magick my_file.png -alpha on -channel rgba ( +clone -channel A -blur 0x2.5 -level 0,80% +channel +level-colors white ) -compose DstOver -composite png32:my_new_file2.png
```

Result:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is an alternative that may work better.

```
magick my_file.png -alpha on \( +clone -channel A -blur 0x2.5 -level 0,80% +channel -channel rgb +level-colors white +channel \) -compose DstOver -composite png32:my_new_file2.png
```